# How to detect if a custom field is present using only a Visualforce expression?

Tags: visualforce, sobjecttype, sobjectfield

I have a field (defined by a 3rd party package) that I need to include in some forms in my package if the field is present on the Contact object (i.e. if the 3rd party package is installed).

I'm looking for a **purely Visualforce** way of doing this and have found that this doesn't work:

```
<apex:inputField
        value="{!Contact['ns__Field__c']}"
        rendered="{! $ObjectType.Contact.fields['ns__Field__c'] != null }"
        />
```

as it produces an error page when the field is missing (in API 31.0):

> Unknown property '$ObjectType.Contact.fields.ns__Field__c' Error is in
>   expression '{!$ObjectType.Contact.fields['ns__Field__c'] != null}' in
>   component ... in component ... Error evaluating dynamic reference
>   'ns__Field__c'

Is there a way of doing this in Visualforce or will I need to resort to a controller property? (I have a couple of levels of components so it will be clumsy to pass the controller property around.)

Comment: I've briefly tried to make it work and eventually gave up, created a fieldset ;) End users of my package are told to add that 3rd party field manually. It's sold as "it's not a bug, it's a feature" ;) Look, you can decide what you want there and in what order :D

Comment: @eyescream Yeah I'm not optimistic - looks like the map syntax is cosmetic and gets translated to a compile-time checked reference. The field in question is a hidden field needed to make the 3rd party package work so no-one really wants to have to configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is no and this has to be done in Apex:

```
public static Boolean hasFieldXyz {
    get {
        if (hasFieldXyz == null) {
            hasFieldXyz = Contact.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet().contains('Xyz__c');
        }
        return hasFieldXyz;
    }
    private set;
}
```